# It is possible to have .load inside php foreach

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, foreach

I was wondering if its possible to have `.load` inside a foreach loop. I currently have tried it but doesn't do what i thought it would do:

```
<?php
foreach($comments as $comment) {
    echo "<div class='wrap'>";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(".post4divv div").load("lonelypost.php?idfrompost=<?php echo $post_idr; ?> .div12");</script>
<?php echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Now every time it loops I want to add the `.load` data to each `$("div.wrap")` the foreach echos out per loop

Comment: This is very bad practise. You should perform an AJAX request from the client to the server, receive an object of data and make the javascript go through the data object and perform the action you want. "but doesn't do what i thought it would do" What is it doing then?

Comment: beside I think this look like really bad practice. you do not have a </script> in your code to close the javascript tag

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php 
  foreach($comments as $comment) {
    echo "<div class='wrap'>";
?>
$(".post4divv div").load("lonelypost.php?idfrompost=" + <?php echo $post_idr; ?> + "div12");

<?php 
  echo "</div>";
}
?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a very bad practice if you use .load function inside foreach as it will decrease the loading speed and might b possible that your browser will be hanged out in case of large data loop.

anyway answer for your problem is

```
   foreach($comments as $comment){
    echo "<div class='wrap'>";
    echo "<script>";
    echo "$('some selector').load('whatever you want to')";
    echo "</script>";
    echo "</div>";
   }
```

But the better solution is to usejQuery Template. call an Ajax request as mentioned in comment by @Jonast92. get data in JSON format from php. and with help of jquery template you can display your whole json array in loop.

Please let me know if this solves your problem as you haven't specified your problem in details with requirement.

---

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but

```
<?php
foreach($comments as $comment) {
?>
<div class='wrap' name='<?=$post_idr?>'>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $("div.wrap[name='<?=$post_idr?>']")
      .load("lonelypost.php?idfrompost=<?=$post_idr?> .div12");
</script>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

would load each individual comment into its own div.

Comment: Why do you use the `name` attribute? It is only used on form elements.

Comment: Exactly, it stores data and won't be called.  You could do it with `this` statements given primarily ajax code, but that would require a lot of rewriting for our friend here.
You can even invent tag attributes to store data, but early versions of IE don't support that, so `name` is a good way to cheat.

Comment: Using something like an `id` or `class`, perhaps with a prefix, or even the `data-*` attribute, would be more correct. The `name` attribute is supposed to be used for form elements and anchors.

Comment: I had thought that data-* breaks in early IE too, but you're probably right.  Works the same either way.